# Calling data in a column of different sheet to be pasted in the main sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to call raw data from another sheet in different workbook (a column from the sheet) to fill up the column in the main sheet but both column sizes are different. I would like to use button in the main sheet whereby when I click the button, the data will be called automatically. Can this be done?

Comment: It is certainly relevant and it is easily done, but probably would be helpful if you elaborated a little bit.  Can you please explain what you mean by `but both column sizes are different`?

Comment: hiiii....psubsee2003 it very sweeet of you to drop by... (but both column sizes are different) means that the raw data column and the column which is calling the raw data are in different sizes.thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for starters..

```
Sub temp()
Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("file path")

wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
wb1.Activate
wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 This should do it. However three suggestions :) 

`1` You have declared wb1 as a variant. You might want to do this? Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook 

`2` When using Range Object and Rows() it is better to fully qualify them for example wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B" & wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy

CONTD...

Comment: CONTD from above...

If you do not want to write such a long line of code then you can engulf the above in With End With statement as well :)

`3` There is no need to Activate and select ranges. You can directly perform the action. For example

wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B" & wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")

Comment: Sifdhart. i agree with u about including the worksheet reff everywhere. but dim wb1, wb2 as workbook should declare both as workbooks. isnt it?

Comment: No it doesn't. The first one will be declared as a variant and the 2nd one will be declared as a workbook.